# lastInsertId() de PDO o SELECT MAX('id') de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Se me presenta la siguiente duda al momento de querer insertar en dos tablas, y esta es en que seria lo mejor o mas optimo al momento de recuperar el ultimo id insertado de una tabla para posteriormente este ser insertado en otra tabla que esta debidamente relacionada.

Siempre o casi siempre he utilizado el `lastInsertId()` de PDO, pero mas que todos lo he utilizado en proyectos en donde no existe casi trafico de usuarios. Leyendo el manual este método devuelve el ultimo id insertado en la base de datos en la conexión actual. Ahora me pregunto, cuando el sistema tenga un trafico de usuarios alto este método podría devolver un id que no sea el correcto al de la inserción que pertenece al script que se ejecuto? ya que como dice el manual el método devuelve el ultimo id insertado en la base de datos y no el ultimo id insertado en una tabla especifica.

Para ello he pensado que el `SELECT MAX(id) as last_id FROM usuarios;` puede ser mas útil ya que este devuelve el ultimo id insertado de la tabla que se quiera.

La pregunta es, cual es mas útil utilizar y porque, y cual es mas optimo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si se trata de conocer el último id insertado en una columna autoincremental en ese momento preciso queda claro que la opción más exacta es:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as last_id FROM usuarios;
```

Como es evidente, la consulta devolverá el mayor `id` que exista en ese momento.

La [información del Manual de PHP sobre `lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php) no es clara, de hecho, no afirma algo que es determinante para responder a tu pregunta: este método ***devuelve el último id generado por la conexión actual***.

Supongamos entonces el siguiente escenario:

- **Último id actual: `44`**
- **Conexión 1:** inserta 3 registros y luego ejecuta `lastInsertId`. Para Conexión 1 este valor será 47.
- **Conexión 2:** inserta 2 registros y luego ejecuta `lastInsertId`. Para Conexión 2 este valor será 49.

Tenemos entonces dos valores diferentes para `lastInsertId`, los cuales son `47` para Conexión 1 y `49` para Conexión 2.

Lo que afirmo en este escenario es sostenido por [lo que afirma la documentación sobre el comportamiento de `LAST_INSERT_ID` en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   ***per-connection basis***. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first `AUTO_INCREMENT` value
>   generated for most recent statement affecting an `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>   column ***by that client***. This value cannot be affected by other
>   clients, even if they generate `AUTO_INCREMENT` values of their own.
>   This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without
>   concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for
>   locks or transactions.

---

> La ID que se generó se mantiene en el servidor ***por conexión***.
>   Esto significa que el valor devuelto por la función a un cliente dado
>   es el primer valor de `AUTO_INCREMENT` generado para la declaración
>   más reciente que afecta a una columna `AUTO_INCREMENT` ***por ese
>   cliente***. Este valor no puede verse afectado por otros clientes,
>   incluso si generan sus propios valores `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Este
>   comportamiento garantiza que cada cliente pueda recuperar su propia ID
>   sin preocuparse por la actividad de otros clientes, y sin la necesidad
>   de bloqueos o transacciones.

Como dice la documentación, `lastInsertId` sirve **precisamente** para asegurar que cada conexión pueda trabajar **con su propio último id generado**. Si lo que se quiere es saber cuál es el el último id real que existe en la tabla, el mejor camino es usar `MAX(id)`.

---

### Otras referencias

Se puede ver las siguientes preguntas y sus respuestas:

- [PDO Last Insert ID always the right one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9891945/5587982)
- [Thread safety of MySql's Select Last_Insert_ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30959678/5587982)
- [LAST_INSERT_ID() how it works at multi-users environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5835677/5587982)

Comment: Excelente respuesta, ahora si me queda claro que es lo mas optimo para utilizar. Clarisimo como siempre A. Cedano, Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta sobre el trafico de usuarios;

puedes utilizar `lastInsertId()` de PDO sin ningún problema en sistemas donde tengas muchos clientes ya que cada conexión de usuarios es independiente de las demás, por ejemplo cuando realizas un nuevo `insert` y si MySQL ejecuta con éxito esta consulta, entonces MySQL envía un `OK_Packet` como respuesta.

Esto quiere decir que PDO almacena la informacion del registro insertado en esa ejecucion del script.

En el servidor, internamente se ejecuta select `last_insert_id()` *(Que es el que recuperas con el metodo `lastInsertId()` de PDO )* se ejecuta para llenar este valor en el paquete OK. El controlador recupera la última identificación insertada del paquete y, a su vez, PDO recupera el valor del controlador.

En resumen es seguro utilizar `lastInsertId()` ya que el ID que recuperes sera el ID de esa ejecución de script y no la de otra ejecución a diferencia de usar `SELECT MAX(id)` seria muy peligroso

Comment: Buena tu explicación Albert, muchas gracias por aclararme aun mas el tema.